# Meaning of וש"נ

Tags: talmud-gemara

Often the Mesuras HaShas in the top corner of each Amud of gemara will quote the source or other places a certain concept or sugya can be found. Sometimes, when there are a lot of other places one can find a concept, the Mesuras HaShas will write one (or more) Shas place, and then say "וש"נ". What does that stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ושם נסמן, and there it is listed. It's  referring to the first place that something is mentioned, and there is the complete cross-reference.